# Is there anyway to upgrade from Win 7 beta to the RC?

Tags: windows, windows-7, installation

I am running Win7 beta on a pc and would just like to update it to the RC. I have read that Mircosoft don't want you to upgrade and for that reason have turned upgrading off. Is there a way to upgrade that machine without having to reinstall a lot of software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look the instructions on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/04/07/delivering-a-quality-upgrade-experience.aspx) from the [Engineering Windows 7 blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/).

Comment: Think about your justification. The hack does work, but in the long run, you;re better off with a clean install. I'll be upgrading 4 machines in total and will be using the upgrade hack on only one of them (because it would take too much time to do a complete reinstall). But even that will be nuked-and-paved at RTM.